# .map is not a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have been trying to use the map method on an array in javascript here is the snapshot of the array I have been using.

```
[
   {"name":"supplier","elements":["beta","gama","alpha"]},
   {"name":"commodity","elements":[]},
   {"name":"year","elements":[]}
]
```

This is my usage of map

```
function renderTable(entityMap){
  return entityMap.map((lookup,index)=>{
    console.log(lookup)
    const {name, elements} = lookup
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
      <td>{name}</td>
      <td>{elements}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
```

And I know that I am using the correct array because when i do

```
console.log(entityMap[1])
```

it returns `{name: "commodity", elements: Array(0)}`

UPDATE

I am calling the renderTable function inside render()

```
class LookupTable extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      close,
      saveAndClose,
      entityNames,
      entityModal,
      entityMap
    } = this.props
    console.log(entityMap[1])

    return (
      <Modal 
        title='Add Lookups for entities'
        visible={Boolean(entityModal)}
        onOk={() => saveAndClose()}
        onCancel={() => close()}
        okText='save'
      >
          <div>
            <table>
              <tbody>
              {renderTable({entityMap})}
              </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>

      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

UPDATE 2

Array.isArray(entityMap) returns true

Comment: Who invokes `renderTable` ? It needs to pass  `entityMap`, not `entityMap[1]`

Comment: You can check whether it is an array or not using Array.isArray(entityMap)

Comment: Those missing semi-colons in `renderTable` aren't helping.

Comment: Where are you adding the `console.log(entityMap[1])`? Is the array populated asynchronously? This is not a [mcve]

Comment: @selbie I am passing entityMap not entityMap[1]. i just printed entityMap[1] so that i can check if its an array

Comment: @Vidhyanshujain Did you do like `return renderTable(entityMap)`?

Comment: @Vidhyanshujain It would be better if you can update question with complete component code.

Comment: `entityMap[1]` does not ensure that `entityMap` is an Array.

Comment: @Vidhyanshujain stated as is, your question lacks a lot of information. 1. No reproducible example. If for some reason you can't, 2. no stack trace (we are not sure the ```.map``` error refer to the line you actually posted). 3. No ```console.log``` of ```entityMap``` in you code: we don't know what it is__just__ before invoking ```map```. 4. we don't know either if the "array" you post is written by hand or the output of ```console.log``` (former case could be you actually use a {} with numeric keys)

Comment: @grodzi Array.isArray(entityMap) returns true and I am passing the array as parameter to the renderTable function. The question is that the stack trace says that entityMap.map is not a function but we know entityMap is an array

Comment: You are destructuring the array object while calling renderTable {renderTable({entityMap})}, instead pass the array directly  to  {renderTable(entityMap)}

Comment: You're **not** passing an array to `renderTable`! `renderTable({entityMap})` === `renderTable({ "entityMap": entityMap })` and is basically the same as `var tmp = new Object(); tmp.entityMap = entityMap; renderTable(tmp);`.

Comment: conclusion: pass an array to ```renderTable```, or destructure from ```renderTable({entityMap})``` __signature__. And to __investigate__ do not put ```Array.isArray``` or more generally ```console.log``` at random places, but first to the closest location prior to your error (in this case before the ```return entityMap.map``` line)

Comment: @grodzi Thanks will take precautions from now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the curly braces where you are calling renderTable because the map method works with arrays not with objects.

I have added code where you need to remove curly braces, i hope it will help

```html
<tbody>
  {renderTable(entityMap)}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes!! thanks I just didn't realise that I don't need to add curly braces again. Thanks a lot